# Any documented applications of engineering psychology?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Do you know about any documented application of engineering psychology?

If you know about something, please provide your answer with a reference.

Comment: Not necessarily documented, but you could consider any sort of ergonomically designed equipment to be an application of engineering psychology

Answer (score 1):

After some brief research, it seems that most mechanical forms that are designed with human use in mind are examples of engineering psychology. Engineering psychologists specialize in the relationship between humans and the products we use every day.

Tufts University, MA, offers a major in engineering psychology called "[Bachelor of Science in Human Factors Engineering (Engineering Psychology)](http://engineering.tufts.edu/me/undergraduate/bs/)" which seems to support this idea.

So any tool that has been designed specifically to improve the relationship between humans and their working environment is an applied example. Take, for example, [this hilarious hamster wheel desk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7FioTdZaEk). Probably not the greatest example of engineering psychology, but an interesting example anyway.

Perhaps a more practical example, taken from a [text-book](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8027873-psychology-and-work-today):

> Research by engineering psychologists has demonstrated that using cell phones while driving degrades performance by increasing driver reaction time, particularly among older drivers, and can lead to higher accident risk among drivers of all ages. These and similar research findings are instigating state regulation of cell phone use.